# 正規表現の使い方について・・・

Tags: python, 正規表現

pythonにおいて

```
if(hogehoge(No) >=#####)
```

という文字列にマッチしたら#####(半角数字)の部分を取り出し

```
hogehoge=****
```

という文字列にマッチしたら****(半角数字)を取り出すような正規表現を考えています。
うまい具合に取り出せる書き方はありませんでしょうか？

現在のコードは以下のような感じです。

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import re

def main():

# 日本語に対応した読み出し
f  = codecs.open('C:\workspace\hoge\setting.txt', 'r', 'shift_jis')
data1 = f.read()  # ファイル終端まで全て読んだデータを返す
f.close()
lines1 = data1[:-1].split('\t')

shotNoPattern = r"(if\(hogehoge\(No\) >=(\d{5})\)|hogehoge=(\d{4}))"
for line in lines1:
    #shotNoを検索する
    repatter = re.compile(shotNoPattern)
    matchLine = repatter.match(line)
    if matchLine:
        print matchLine.group()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

setting.txtの中身は以下のような感じです

```
if(hogehoge(No) >=12909) 
    hogehoge=600
endif
if(hogehoge(No) >=13155) //たまにコメントがついている
    hogehoge=650
endif
if(hogehoge(No) >=#####) 
    hogehoge=*****
endif
```

※すべてのif(hogehoge(No) >=#####)の後に半角空白が一個入っています・・・

最終目的としましては.txtファイルに記載されている上記のようなテキストから値を取り出し、
[[12909,600],[13155,650],[#####,*****],......]
のような配列にしたいという物です

Comment: word と word の間にスペース類が入っている場合はどうしますか？ 例えば `if ( hogehoge(No) >= #### )` や `hogehoge = ****` などです。また、取り出す数字の桁数は固定ですか？

Comment: 取り出す数字の桁数は固定ですか？
>>数字の文字数は可変です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 最終目的としましては.txtファイルに記載されている上記のようなテキストから値を取り出し、`[[12909,600],[13155,650],[#####,*****],......]` のような配列にしたいという物です

一例として、`endif` で区切って `re.DOTALL(re.S)` でマッチングを行う方法です。

```
def main():
  # 日本語に対応した読み出し
  f  = codecs.open('C:\workspace\hoge\setting.txt', 'r', 'shift_jis')
  data1 = f.read()  # ファイル終端まで全て読んだデータを返す
  f.close()
  lines1 = data1[:-1].split('endif')

  shotNoPattern = r'.*if\(hogehoge\(No\) >=(\d+)\).+?hogehoge=(\d+)'
  repatter = re.compile(shotNoPattern, re.S)
  pair_array = []
  for line in lines1:
    # shotNoを検索する
    matchLine = repatter.match(line)
    if matchLine:
      pair_array.append([int(x) for x in matchLine.group(1,2)])

  print pair_array

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if\(hogehoge\(No\) >=(\d+)\).*?hogehoge=(\d+)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[実行サンプル](https://regex101.com/r/qI9iT3/3)

コンパイルオプション（`re.S`）が必要になります。

```
re.compile('if\(hogehoge\(No\) >=(\d+)\).*?hogehoge=(\d+)', re.S)
```

Comment: 教えて頂いた方法を反映し、追加情報に記載しましたがうまくマッチしないようです・・・。追加情報にあるような書き方でよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: @Dawachin 2行セットでマッチする形に修正しました。

Comment: このナイスな状態遷移図はどうやって作ったのですか？

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi http://regexper.com/ です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。社内で広めました。